# After switching computers, my rig is completely broken?

Tags: animation, rigging, eevee-render-engine

So I'm Modeling Korra from TLOK, and I switched laptops. Both Laptops were using Ubuntu based OS's, one of them being a chromebook running GalliumOS (ubuntu version 18) and this one being a standard HP laptop running Kubuntu (version 20)

I have no idea what could have caused the errors I'm experiencing. Essentially, parts of the model turn invisible, and when trying to rotate joints on the rig, they go completely crazy and the verticies spread out randomly in every direction.

I've tried 2.9, 2.83 (all LTS versions), nothing works...
[image: korra1]

[image: korra2]
In this gallery there is an image and video of what I'm talking about.

Blend file link: [image]

I appreciate anyone who helps me with this ;-;-;

Comment: Is there a GPU difference between the two computers? Is it possible the HP laptop (if that's the one with the problem) has an incompatible graphics card or out of date drivers?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The HP laptop uses an APU, (it's an a6 iirc) and the chromebook just uses intel accelerated graphics. So the difference is AMD and Intel but i'm not sure it's enough to make a huge deal

Comment: Blender 2.8+ comes with a newer set of minimum standards with regards to graphics capability - only cards that support OpenGL3.3, and even then some didn't make the cut. I also often see users with issues specifically regarding older (and some newer) AMD cards. Documentation and list of supported cards is here - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/